# Using aggregation to eliminate collections matching from another

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using mongodb with nodejs and have two models, ***viewed_blogs*** and ***blogs***.
**blogs** has _id as primary key and  **viewed_blogs** stores user_id and array of blog_id(Which stores all viewed blogs) in fields named *user* and *blogs* resectively.
eg.

> `{ _id: ObjectId("610306e2b978718afa1b61ea"),   user: ObjectId("61010c7a6ca4f103aa52c884"),   __v: 0,   blogs: [ ObjectId("61006c4d8785da0d028f233a") ] }`

Now while giving result, i want to give user all unviewed blogs with a single query. I have tried following aggregation query:

```
{ $match: { user: ObjectId("61010c7a6ca4f103aa52c884") } },
   {
      $lookup:
         {
           from: "blogs",
           pipeline: [
              { $match: { _id : { $nin: "$blogs" } } }
           ],
           as: "viewed_blogs"
         }
    }
])
```

But I am getting **MongoError: $nin needs an array** error. Please suggest some solution. I have tried many alternate ways.

Comment: Try using `$nin: ["$blogs"]` Check the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/). If you want to match one value try `$ne`

Comment: But isn't the "$blogs" already an array?